# Video still loads over https even after I changed the src attribute?

Tags: javascript, ssl, video

I'm wrote a small JS code which changes `src` attribute urls from https to http.
I'm doing this because my company shapes SSL traffic to prevent SSTP and SSL tunnels to outside which caused webpages to malfunction specially video and streams which are served over https.
Here is the code:

```
function changeSrc(){
var srclist = document.getElementsByTagName('source'); //find all source tags

for (var i = 0; i < srclist.length; i++) {
    src = srclist[i].getAttribute("src"); //get current https source
    newsrc = src.replace("https", "http"); //change https to http
    srclist[i].setAttribute("src", newsrc); // replace src attrib. with new url
}
}
```

This function runs just fine (as a tampermonkey extention) but the problem is that videos still play over https even after their `src` is changed.
I suspect may be the player remembers the first video url (https one) and after changing the url, it needs some kind of refresh or something to buffer and play over the new http url?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**doesn't work, I don't think you can do this with audio/video tags**

no experience with tampermonkey, years of greasemonkey though

but I have to ask, why do you need to change https to http?

anyway, what you may want to do is remove the containing video/audio element from the DOM, change the source src in the removed fragment, then re-insert the video/audio fragment element back in where it came from

I think this may do what I described (**untested**)

```
function changeSrc(){
    var mmlist = document.body.querySelectorAll('video,audio'); //find all video/audio tags

    for (var i=0; i<mmlist.length; i++) {
        var mm = mmlist[i];
        var par = mm.parentElement;
        var sib = mm.nextSibling;
        par.removeChild(mm);
        var srclist = mm.querySelectorAll('source');
        for (var j = 0; j < srclist.length; j++) {
            var src = srclist[j].getAttribute('src');
            var newsrc = src.replace("https", "http");
            srclist[j].setAttribute('src', newsrc);
        }
        // par.removeChild(mm); could do it here instead, maybe?
        par.insertBefore(mm, sib);
    }
}
```

to be honest, you may not need to remove the audio/video tag at all .. just the par.insertBefore(mm, sib) may be enough

Comment: Thanks! I'm doing this because my company shapes SSL traffic to prevent SSTP and SSL tunnels to outside which caused webpages to malfunction specially video and streams which are served over https .

Comment: Would you please provide a simple code sample if possible? It would be so much appreciated.
btw, tampermonkey is the same for chrome. Not much difference.

Comment: Thanks. mmm, I'm not sure if I quite understand what it actually do, but it causes the page to crash. I'm looking into it, any suggestions?

Comment: I may well be doing something very wrong in the code - or it may be that chrome does not like video/audio tags manipulated like that - any console logs?

Comment: Found the problem, `for var(i = 0; i < mmlist.length; i++)` var is outside the `(`, it should be `for (var i = 0; i < mmlist.length; i++)` .
Well, That was the thing that caused crash,
But here is the other one, All `<source>` and `<video>` tags are removed and haven't added again. Console output: `Uncaught TypeError: srclist[j].getAttributes is not a function`

Comment: getAttribute ... my typing is bad tonight :p

Comment: I know this doesn't work on youtube - no idea what site you're testing

Comment: Well, it worked like it should, removed then added the DOM element, but video still loads from the HTTPS url ( I'm checking this using web sniffer chrome extension.)

Comment: I think the issue is that the source tags don't have https in the url, as it's possibly a 'relative' url - so your original method is just as likely to work as any, just a matter of putting in the FULL url in the src

Comment: They have full url in their src attribute.